$\lim _{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\; dx$, $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\infty\frac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx}\cos x\; dx$ DCT
I have to evaluate the following limits using the dominated convergence theorem: $t\in (0,\infty)$
$$(1)\quad \lim _{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\; dx$$
$$(2)\quad \lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\infty\frac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx}\cos x\; dx$$
Proof. $(1)$ We note that $$\left |e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x }{x}\right |\le e^{-tx}\le e^{-rx}\quad \forall t\ge r>0,\quad \forall x>0$$
and $$\int_0^\infty e^{-rx}\; dx=\frac{1}{r}<\infty$$ and then $e^{-rx}\in L^1([0,\infty))$. Thus for DCT we have $$\lim _{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\; dx=\int_0^\infty \left(\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\;dx=0.$$
$(2)$ $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\infty\frac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx}\cos x\; dx=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\infty\left(\lim_{t \to 0^+} (1+tx)e^{-tx}\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right)\; dx=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\; dx.$$
In this case I can't give a limitation with an integrable function, because we have that $$\left |\frac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx}\cos x\right |\le (1+tx)e^{-tx}.$$ What don't I see?

As $-1\le \cos(x) \le 1$ you have
$$
 \left|\dfrac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx}\cos(x) \right| \le \left| \dfrac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx} \right|
$$
But, if we assume $t \ge 0$
$$
\int_{\pi/2}^\infty \left| \dfrac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx} \right| dx = \int_{\pi/2}^\infty  \frac{e^{-tx}}{x^2}\ dx + \int_{\pi/2}^\infty  \frac{te^{-tx}}{x}dx=
$$
$$
=-\dfrac{e^{-tx}}{x} \Big|^\infty_{\pi/2}- t\int_{\pi/2}^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{x}dx+ 
 t\int_{\pi/2}^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{x}dx= \frac{2}{\pi} e^{-\frac{t\pi}{2}}
$$
So, for each $ t \ge 0$
$$
\left| \dfrac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx} \right| \in L^1\left( \left[\frac{\pi}2, \infty\right)\right)
$$
That is exactly what you are looking for

Thanks! Maybe you forgot to remove an $x^2$?

@NatMath   Why should I remove $x^2$? I used $\frac{1+tx}{x^2}e^{-tx}$ to dominate the integral.

If you remove $x^2$ you obtain $$\int_{\pi/2}^\infty (1+tx) e^{-tx} dx= \dfrac{e^{-t\pi/2}(\pi t + 4)}{2t}$$ that is not integrable for $t=0$

@ Marco I don't understand how you solved  $$\int_{\pi/2}^\infty  \frac{e^{-tx}}{x^2}\ dx$$

@NatMath Integrate by part and obtain $$ -\frac{e^{-tx} }{x}\big|^\infty_{\pi/2} -t\int_{\pi/2}^\infty \frac{e^{tx}}{x} dx $$
